# how to retrieve email type fields from lead object in salesforce?

Tags: query

In my case, i have more than one fields are email type in my lead object.using query based,i need to retrieve the particular email type fields.how to write query for that? pls help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can get all the email type field of any object using the describe
>   call.

```
String strEmailFiels = '';
for(Schema.SObjectField field : Lead.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
{
    if(Schema.DisplayType.EMAIL == field.getDescribe().getType())
        strEmailFiels += ', ' + field.getDescribe().getName();

}
strEmailFiels = strEmailFiels.removeStart(',');
system.debug('======strEmailFiels======='+strEmailFiels);
```

> Then you can use those email type fields in soql query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Describe Call on an Object to retrieve all fields and then check for field type. For email fields the type of a field will be **EMAIL**

After identifying EMAIL type fields you can create a dynamic string which will be a query string for a Dynamic Query.

```
String obj = 'Lead';

Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(obj); 
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sobjType.getDescribe(); 
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = describeResult.fields.getMap(); 
Map<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult> finalMap = 
    new Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
for(String field : fieldsMap.keySet()){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dr = fieldsMap.get(field).getDescribe();
    finalMap.put(field, dr);
}

List<String> emailFields = new List<String>();

for (String field : fieldsMap.keySet()) {  
  System.debug(finalMap.get(field).getName()); // field name
  System.debug(finalMap.get(field).getType()); // field type for email will BE EMAIL
  System.debug(finalMap.get(field).getLength()); // field length
if(String.valueOf(finalMap.get(field).getType()).equalsIgnoreCase('EMAIL')){
emailFields.add(field);
}
}

System.debug('::'+emailFields);

String query =
  ' SELECT ' +
      String.join( emailFields, ',' ) +
  ' FROM Lead ' +
  ' LIMIT 100 '
;

// return generic list of sobjects or typecast to expected type
List<SObject> leadList = Database.query( query );

System.debug('Lead records ::'+leadList);
```

[References](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)